# Как сделать чтобы текст кнопки менялся с ,,Сховати'' на ,,Показати''?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть работающий код. Как сделать чтобы текст кнопки менялся с ,,Сховати'' на ,,Показати''?

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    let [isHeaderVisible, setHeaderVisible] = useState(true);

    let click = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }

    let toggleHeader = () => {
        setHeaderVisible(!isHeaderVisible);
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{counter}</h2>
            <button onClick={click}>Збільшити значення</button>
            <button onClick={minusClick}>Зменшити значення</button>

            {isHeaderVisible && 
                <div>vgkfrvfcslkrgvewgtrperlfwepwerferwfwerwer</div>
            }
            <button onClick={toggleHeader}>Сховати</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте тернарный оператор

`<button onClick={toggleHeader}>{isHeaderVisible ? 'Сховати' : 'Показати'}</button>`